# After adding additional features, same accuracy on test data, but higher accuracy on training data, how should I interpret ?

Tags: svm, cross-validation, feature-selection

I've done 5-fold cross-validation and the model is SVM.

300 features: 0.53 on test, 0.55 on training;

700 featuers: 0.53 on test, 0.67 on training.

Does this mean that the additional 400 features is useless ?

Comment: It depends on the size of the dataset you are using to train the model. If you added new features and performance increased on the training set but nothing or lower for testing, my guess is that you are starting to overfit.

Comment: @xeon, SVM is a max-margin classifier. Does it mean that it can avoid overfitting to some extent ?

Comment: SVMs are not guaranteed to be overfit-proof. They have nice properties of generalization but not guarantees that you will always learn from data. The power of SVMs lies in custom kernels, which if used properly, can map your data in a new space where separation is much easier than in the original feature space.

Comment: @xeon, I think my results just shows the SVM's power. Even though it "overfits" on training data, but it still maintains a not-worse result on testing data. In my opinion, the overfitting problem is that the model overfits the noise in the training data, and lost the real underlying trends in the data, which will lead to a much worse results on testing.

Comment: Let me kindly disagree. You showed that after addition of 400 new features the performance improved *only* on the training set and stayed the same on the test set. You are interested of the performance on out-of-sample dataset, not on the training set since the error on training set is not a good indicator how well you learned.

Comment: Can you provide the sizes of training and testing sets you are using in your experiment?

Comment: @xeon I have 4000 data points. I do 5-fold cross-validation. I agree that it's overfitting on the training data, but the overfitting in SVM seems doesn't hurt the performance on testing data. My question is, we I do prediction on some other dataset, should I use my 700 features of just 300 features ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have overfitting on training data.you can go to this link for solving this matter : 
http://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_we_solve_an_overfitting_problem

Answer (score 0):

Usually you pick the smallest possible set of features with the highest accuracy on the testing set. If your dataset is not balanced however check the acquired confusion matrices or use a metric that is not affected by skewed classes.